# How to Find the space/size occupied by the List Symbol of a given font in Itext Java

Tags: java, list, itext, chunks

I am trying to generate a pdf with paragraphs that are put in a List. I will be using the list symbol for numbering the paragraphs. Now I need to find the space/size being occupied by the list symbol. How do I do that? 
The auto indent function of the list calculates the space of the list symbol to make the next lines in the para indented. I need the space/indentation being used for the list symbol. Also what is the unit of measurement for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the list symbol as a `String`, the space occupied will depend on the font and the font size. The `BaseFont` class has the following method you can use: `BaseFont.getWidthPoint(String text, float fontSize)`.

If you have the list symbol as a `Chunk`, the `Chunk` contains the `String`, the `BaseFont` and the font size. In that case, you can use `chunk.getWidthPoint()`.

These methods are somewhat misleading as they contain the word `Point`. In reality, als measurements are done in *user units*. By default, 1 inch equals 72 user units. The same is true for points, hence the method names. However, in rare cases, the default user unit can be changed. The confusion between *user unit* and *point* exists in ISO-32000-1 and earlier PDF specifications, as well as in iText 5 and earlier iText versions. The confusion is avoided in ISO-32000-2 and starting with iText 7.